# While loop uses the same value each time

Tags: c++, validation, input, while-loop, iostream

I have the problem with my code. There is while loop and when a enter not a number and for example character data, so then this loop uses the same value of choice each time.
It's a list where user should choose one of variants. Choice it's a user's choice. There should be only integer value and I have trouble with character.

For example:
choice = a;
so then I can't change it ever, because loop doesn't work.
if choice = 2, it works good and I can change choice while loop is working.

```
int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string fname;
    Data object;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Введите имя файла: ";
        out << "Введите имя файла: ";
        cin >> fname;
        out << fname;
        object.CreateAndRecordToFile(fname);
    }
    while (nameisright == false);


    std::cout << "Создан файл для записи " << object.ffullname << endl;
    out.open(object.ffullname, ofstream::out);// открываю созданный файл и говорю, что хочу в него записывать


    int ch1, ch2;
    bool prov = true;
    int choice;

    while (prov)
    {

        std::cout << "Выберите, пожалуйста, метод решения СЛАУ:" << endl;
        out << "Выберите, пожалуйста, метод решения СЛАУ:";
        std::cout << "1. Метод Гаусса \n";
        out << "1. Метод Гаусса \n";
        std::cout << "2. Метод LU разложения\n";
        out << "2. Метод LU разложения\n";
        std::cout << "3. Выход\n";
        out << "3. Выход\n";
        std::cout << "Ваш выбор: ";
        out << "Ваш выбор: ";
        cin >> choice;
        //char ccc[200];
        //cin >> ccc;
        /*while (false){
            if (strlen(ccc) != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ccc); i++) {
            if (!isdigit(ccc[1])){
            std::cout << ccc[i] << " is not numeric.\n";
            return false;
            }
            }
            }
            }*/

        //else

        //choice = stoi(ccc);

        //out << ccc;
        //check(choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:            // Гаусс 
        {


            std::cout << "Выберите, пожалуйста, метод ввода данных:" << endl;
            out << "Выберите, пожалуйста, метод ввода данных: ";
            std::cout << "1. Ввод данных с клавиатуры \n";
            out << "1. Ввод данных с клавиатуры  \n";
            std::cout << "2. Ввод данных из файла \n";
            out << "2. Ввод данных из файла\n";
            std::cout << "3. Выход\n";
            out << "3. Выход\n";
            std::cout << "Ваш выбор: ";
            out << "Ваш выбор: ";
            cin >> ch1;
            out << ch1;
            switch (ch1)
            {
            case 1:
                object.Size();
                object.Init();
                object.MatrixInPut();
                object.InitAndInputVector();
                object.printAll();
                object.GaussElimination();
                object.printResultGauss();
                break;
            case 2:
                object.ReadingSize();
                object.Init();
                object.ReadingMatrixFromFile();
                object.ReadingVectorFromFile();
                object.printAll();
                object.GaussElimination();
                object.printResultGauss();

                break;
            case 3:            // Просто прощайте
                std::cout << endl;
                out << endl;
                std::cout << "Спасибо, что были с нами!\n";
                out << "Спасибо, что были с нами!\n";
                prov = false;
                break;
            default:            // На случай фейлов
                std::cout << endl;
                out << endl;
                std::cout << "Ошибка, некорректный ввод, повторите ввод.\n";
                out << "Ошибка, некорректный ввод, повторите ввод.\n";
                break;
            }

            break;
        case 2:            // ЛУ

        {


            std::cout << "Выберите, пожалуйста, метод ввода данных:" << endl;
            out << "Выберите, пожалуйста, метод ввода данных: ";
            std::cout << "1. Ввод данных с клавиатуры \n";
            out << "1. Ввод данных с клавиатуры  \n";
            std::cout << "2. Ввод данных из файла \n";
            out << "2. Ввод данных из файла\n";
            std::cout << "3. Выход\n";
            out << "3. Выход\n";
            std::cout << "Ваш выбор: ";
            out << "Ваш выбор: ";
            cin >> ch2;
            out << ch2;
            switch (ch2)
            {
            case 1:
                object.Size();
                object.Init();
                object.MatrixInPut();
                object.printMatrix();
                object.LUdecomposition();
                object.printLU();
                break;
            case 2:
                object.ReadingSize();
                object.Init();
                object.ReadingMatrixFromFile();
                object.printMatrix();
                object.LUdecomposition();
                object.printLU();
                break;
            case 3:            // Просто прощайте
                std::cout << endl;
                out << endl;
                std::cout << "Спасибо, что были с нами!\n";
                out << "Спасибо, что были с нами!\n";
                prov = false;
                break;
            default:            // На случай фейлов
                std::cout << endl;
                out << endl;
                std::cout << "Ошибка, некорректный ввод, повторите ввод.\n";
                out << "Ошибка, некорректный ввод, повторите ввод.\n";
                break;


            }
            break;
        case 3:            // Просто прощайте
            std::cout << endl;
            out << endl;
            std::cout << "Спасибо, что были с нами!\n";
            out << "Спасибо, что были с нами!\n";
            prov = false;
            break;
        default:            // На случай фейлов
            std::cout << endl;
            out << endl;
            std::cout << "Ошибка, некорректный ввод, повторите ввод.\n";
            out << "Ошибка, некорректный ввод, повторите ввод.\n";
            //choice = 0;
            //prov = false;


        }
        }
        out.close();// закрываю файл 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please make this an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @RichardCritten I do, I see that I enter choice only one time, but should every time. I can't understand it. I just need some help, guys..

Comment: @NathanOliver I will, this is my first post ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choice` is an `int`. When you do `cin>>choice` and the user enters a non numeric value, the failbit is set for `cin`. This bit will make all subsequent input fail as well, until you clear the flag with **[`cin.clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/)** and ignore the wrong input with **[`cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)**.

Example:

```
while ((cin>>choice).fail() && !cin.eof()) {  // if failed but not eof
    cout<<"Enter numeric data ! Please retry... ";
    cin.clear();                  // clear error state
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');     // ignore everything until then end of the line
}
if (cin.eof()) {
    cerr << "FATAL ERROR: unexpected end of file"<<endl; 
    exit(1); 
}
```

Comment: I get it, thanks. Should I use something like cin.clear() or how should I ignore the wrong input?

Comment: Both ! Give me 10 minutes. I'm back home and can use a real keyboard to answer ;-)

Comment: @whoiskatrin edited:  you've the linke to the function reference, as well as an example how to do error processing, reasking the user until he either gives something ok or ends the input.

Comment: oh, thank you. I didn't know about cin.ignore(). Now I understand, can I ask ? What is "cerr" and cin.eof()?

Comment: `cerr` is like `cout`, but it's used only for displaying errors.  cin.eof() tells if end of file was encountered during the last attempt to read the input.

Comment: how can I prevent invalid input, when someone enter numeric data with character data. For example "2sfs", so then program thinks that the "case 2"  was chosen. How can I fix it?

Comment: Then you should `>>`  a string and convert the string to an int, after having verified that it's only composed of digits.

Comment: Please, check my answer, I hope this is that way what you wrote me about.

Comment: Seems fine, if the number is not allowed to be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will useful for someone. If you want to check that an input string has only numeric values, you can do it this way:

```
 bool is_number(const string& str)
 {
      auto it = str.cbegin();
      while (it != str.cend() && isdigit(*it)) ++it;
      return !str.empty() && it == str.cend();
 }


 string choice;
 ...
 cin >> choice; 
 if (!is_number(choice)) {
        cout << "Enter numeric data ! Please retry." << endl;
        cin.clear();                   
 }
 else {
       // process the number 
 }
```

Comment: If you want a constant iterator use cbegin() and cend().  (I've edited)